# Online chess lectures for kids

Tags: learning, training, online

What are sites to learn for kids. Especially, video lectures. The lectures should be simpler to understand.

Comment: Chesskid.com is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to chessyourchild.com, the top 5 sites are:

> 1. chesskid.com
> 2. zoomchess.com
> 3. chesscoachonline.com
> 4. chessclub.com/icckids
> 5. chesscademy.com

There's also a chess.com forum about it: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/safe-chess-sites-for-children

As a child, I used chesskid.com right about when it was established. It was pretty good, but I found nothing worked better than on-the-board learning. It all depends on the psyche of the kid; I recommend that you try these 5 sites and see which fits best.